# Youtube chromeless player not working with playlists on AS3

Tags: javascript, youtube

I had this code on a website to load a Youtube playlist in a chromeless player.

```
player.loadPlaylist({ 
        list:'PLB053FF53834A76D4', 
        listType: 'playlist', 
        index:1, 
        startSeconds:0, 
        suggestedQuality:'medium' 
});
```

It was perfectly working, but now, it does not load the videos. I've tried both with argument and object syntax, but neither of them works. If I try to load a single video, or a playlist giving an array of video IDs as parameter, it works without problem.

Has there been changes in the way the API works?

My last resort would be loading the playlist in an embedded player instead of a chromeless player. How could I load a playlist like that? I've only seen examples with single videos.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what you're looking for:

```
player.loadPlaylist({
    'playlist': 'PLB053FF53834A76D4',
    'startSeconds': 0,
    'endSeconds': 60,
    'suggestedQuality': 'medium'
});
```

[Here’s the latest API documentation.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference)